# json2html, calling JSON data in an array

Tags: json2html

I'm using json2html and trying to figure out the correct syntax for calling JSON data within an array:

```
{ biographicData: [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        birthDate: '10/15/1983',
        email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        workPhone: '678-901-2345',
        mobilePhone: '098-765-4321',
        homePhone: '123-456-7890'
    }
]}
```

In other cases, I've used something like {"tag":"div","html":"${biographicData.firstName}"} to get the values, but that doesn't seem to work when the data is in an array. What do I need to do to fix this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access array data you can do something like this if you know the position of the array you are trying to access

```
{"tag":"div","html":"${biographicData.0.firstName}"}
```

or you could transform the entire array (if there are multiple elements) using an inline function and a transform

```
{"tag":"div","children":function(){
   return( json2html.transform(this,bioDataTransform) );
}}
```

Comment: How would this work with the `required` array in data such as: 
        [{
                "name": "Lorem",
                "types": ["add"],
                "important": false,
                "institution": "something"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ipsum",
                "types": ["copy"],
                "important": false,
                "required": ["one", "two"]
            }
        ]
? Thanks!

Comment: I take it you want to render the "required" array you could use a transform like this on the data {"<>":"div","html":[
 {"<>":"div","text":"${name}"},
 {"<>":"div","html":function(){
     return( this.required.join(",") );
 }
}

Comment: This outputs the same as when I simply call it by `${required}"` – I’m looking for a way to iterate over the array and output elements as `<li>` elements in html. Working with a for-loop to iterate over the array only returns the first value of the required array...
`{"<>": "div", "class": "panel-footer", "html": function () { var arr = this.required; for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { var element = arr[i]; return "<li>" + element + "</li>"; } } }`

Comment: I got it like this: `{ "<>": "div", "class": "panel-footer", "html": function () { var arr = this.required; var output = []; if (arr == undefined) { return "Keine requirements"; } else { for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { var element = arr[i]; output.push(element); } return output.join(""); } } }`

Comment: You could also do it like this if you want it as a list ... { "<>": "ul", "class": "panel-footer", "html": function () { var output = []; if (!this required) { return "Keine requirements"; } else { for (var i = 0; i < this.required.length; i++) { output.push({"val":arr[i]}); } return json2html.transform(output,{"<>":"li","text":"${val}"}) } } }