# json2html - Create inline function for JSON data in array w/ multiple elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, json2html

I have the following JSON data:

```
{"orders":[
{"id":16,"status":"completed","total":"45.00"},
{"id":17,"status":"completed","total":"55.00"}
]}
```

how do I transform this data to html using json2html?
`${orders.0.total}` works but I want it to transform all orders, not just array 0.

I have tried the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382132/json2html-calling-json-data-in-an-array), but it won't work.

This is what I have:

```
<body>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //List items
    var myjson = [{"orders":[
                 {"id":16,"status":"completed","total":"45.00"},
                 {"id":17,"status":"completed","total":"55.00"}
                 ]}];

    //List item transform
    var orderTransform = {"tag":"div","html":"${total}"}

    var transform = {"tag":"div","children":function(){
        return( json2html.transform(this,orderTransform) );
    }};

    $(function(){
        //Create the list
        $('#list').json2html(myjson,transform);
    });
</script>
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transform should be modified to:

```
var transform = {"tag":"div","children":function(){
        return( json2html.transform(this.orders,orderTransform) );
}};
```

Note the change of `this` to `this.orders`, as the root transform references the `{orders: [...]}` object, so in the children function it is necesary to specify the new array that is being used as the data.

The original code passed `this` as the data for the children which would make json2html try to rerender the `{orders: [...]}` object using the orderTransform, which is incorrect, so instead it is important to explicitly specify that the data for that transform is in the `orders` field.